# how to send http request ins pytest"

Tags: flask, python-requests, httprequest, pytest

I'm trying to test a Flask application. I want to send an http request to my endpoints to check if the database was changed.

I'm using pytest on Linux ubuntu 19.4.

```py
from unittest import TestCase
import requests

class TestUser(TestCase):
    def test_create_account(self):
        #doesn't matter
```

when I try to run this, using `pytest`, it crashes.

here's the error I'm  getting:

```
=========================================== ERRORS ===========================================
_____________________________ ERROR collecting test/test_user.py _____________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/rahimi0151/Desktop/cetia_api/cetia_api/test/test_user.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
test/test_user.py:2: in <module>
    import requests
E   ImportError: No module named requests
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
================================== 1 error in 0.08 seconds ===================================
```

and when I try to install requests, here is what will happen:

```
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests) (2.6)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests) (1.24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests) (2018.8.24)
```

I even tried using `sudo` and `--upgrade` (I've read about them on other threads of StackOverflow) but none of them worked.

what should I do?

Comment: Run `pytest -v`, it will print version and location of Python used. Compare it with what `pip --version` shows. Most probably you have two different Python versions installed on your machine, or `pytest` is executed in an isolated virtual environment etc.

Comment: try `which pytest` and `which requests`. It will show the locations of the packages. They should have similar paths. Since you are using python3, you should install the packages in your environment using `pip3 install`. And you should run test with `python3 -m pytest <test-file>`.